# How can I organize snacks effectively without them going bad?

Tags: storage, organization, snack-food

I don't know whether sorting or grouping by expiry date, snack types or size and shapes of the containers are the most effective in terms of organizing my snacks. I have a lot of snacks and am keen on buying more snacks quicker than I could eat.

Since I never have a good habit organizing them, I often find myself regretting - So how should I organize them effectively?

Comment: What's the average time till expiring date for your snacks? Does it vary greatly between the different snacks?

Comment: @Mast: They roughly scale from lasting two months to those which lasts over four years (or so it says on the expiry date), but there are no great gaps among the variations.

Comment: Maybe you need [this fridge](http://xkcd.com/1109/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by expiry date, for sure - once they're past that, you'll just be putting them in the bin, so the point, surely, is to have them in date order so you know what must be eaten first, that's the priority, regardless of the product. That's the way products are stacked on supermarket shelves, with the shortest dated produce to the front, longer at the back. Admittedly, theirs are grouped by the product, then the date, but you've got, presumably, a random selection available, so in those circumstances, the date is the consideration.

As an aside, I'd also say don't buy so many snacks, that'd make life a lot easier (and healthier, probably). And don't shop when you're hungry, you'd be surprised how much easier it is to walk straight past snack type food and only buy what you need when you've got a full stomach.